# R GauPro Package: Why are there only two parameters estimated?

Tags: r, statistics, gaussian-process

So this package uses the Gaussian (which I believe is the squared exponential) covariance function. But by default, only two parameters are optimized: "theta" and "nugget". Shouldn't there be three parameters in a Gaussian process? It appears that the variance in the function is being fixed, but I can't tell from the documentation what the plug-in is. Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance.

```
x <- seq(0,1,l=10)
y <- abs(sin(2*pi*x))^.8
gp<-GauPro(beta_seq,mu_list_train)
gp
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Show the code you are running.

Comment: I can't tell either. I poked through the code on Github a little bit but couldn't easily find where `Kinv` (inverse of the covariance matrix) was being defined ...

Comment: That is reassuring. Thank you.